# Momentjs countdown - Duration is showing negative numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, momentjs, countdown

I am tring to create a countdown with MomentJS (`2.22.2`) and Rxjs (`6.2.2`) `interval`. But when I reach some points in time my countdown goes crazy and outputs negative numbers, where it should have, for example, substracted a day and started at 23 hours.

Any help on how I should fix this?

---

**Example**

local time: `2018-09-05T18:49`

End time: `2018-11-03T18:00`

this results in:

[image: Negative countdown]

---

**My code**

'`this.days`', '`this.hours`', '`this.minutes`' & '`this.seconds`' are local variables that hold a string representation of the resulting time (string format, because I want to show leading zero's)

```
interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      const now = moment();
      let timeLeft = this.endDate.diff(now, 'milliseconds', true);
      let endDate = moment(this.endDate); // Use 'moment' to make a new copy

      // Days
      const days = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asDays());
      console.warn(moment.duration(timeLeft).asDays());
      this.days = Countdown.addLeadingZeros(days.toString(), 3);

      endDate = endDate.subtract(days, 'days');
      timeLeft = endDate.diff(now, 'milliseconds', true);

      // Hours
      const hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asHours());
      console.warn(Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeft).asHours()));
      this.hours = Countdown.addLeadingZeros(hours.toString(), 2);

      endDate = endDate.subtract(hours, 'hours');
      timeLeft = endDate.diff(now, 'milliseconds', true);

      // Minutes
      const minutes = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asMinutes());
      this.minutes = Countdown.addLeadingZeros(minutes.toString(), 2);

      endDate = endDate.subtract(minutes, 'minutes');
      timeLeft = endDate.diff(now, 'milliseconds', true);

      // Seconds
      const seconds = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asSeconds());
      this.seconds = Countdown.addLeadingZeros(seconds.toString(), 2);
});
```

---

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here or how I could improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative numbers arise in your code because of daylight-saving time changes.

Here in the UK there is a change of daylight-savings time between `2018-09-05` and `2018-11-03`.  In fact it is on `2018-10-28`. I can reproduce your problem if I choose two dates on either side of this, but not if both dates are on the same side.  I'm guessing that where you live there is also a change of daylight-savings time between `2018-09-05` and `2018-11-03`.

The simplest way to avoid problems like this is to calculate the time difference using times in UTC.  Instead of writing

```
  const now = moment();
```

write

```
  const now = moment().utc();
```

and ensure that `this.endDate` is created in UTC not local time.

Comment: There is indeed a daylight-saving time set within those dates (maby no longer! https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/eu-end-daylight-savings-time-zones-member-states-europe-a8203446.html)

Anyway, how would you 'revive' a utc date? `moment.utc().toISODate()` gives me:  `2018-09-05T22:45:00.890Z`. But when I do `moment(<date>)` or `moment().utc(<date>)` I get a deprecated warning

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy: For me, `moment("2018-09-05T22:45").utc().format()` prints `2018-09-05T21:45:00Z`.  I can't reproduce a deprecation warning: would it be possible to list the exact strings you are using when you write `<date>`?  It's also not clear what you mean by 'revive' - could you explain more?

Comment: I was doing `moment().utc().toISODate()` and restoring the string via `moment(<iso-string>).utc()`, where I should be doing `moment().utc().format()` for the string and `moment(<date>).utc()` for a moment date. It works now. Thank you very much!